# How do I use WebAPI/Rest correctly when other params are needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am new to WebAPI and rest and am trying to do things correctly.  By default if I were to access something such as User I would call api/user/5 if I wanted user 5.  This would go to my User controller to Get(int num) I think.  But I know I will often need other params passed as well.  Currently I have Get(JObject data), but that data param is for other parameters.  I will need other optional params whether I am sending an ID or wanting a list of everything.   How do I go about organizing methods properly with WebAPI?  Am I misunderstanding something?

To clarify:
This question is more about REST than dynamic objects, though they play a part:

How do I get a single resource vs a list of resources when I need additional params.  I see those concepts as two separate methods, but the additional params complicate it in my mind when routing is involved.

Comment: Are you coding in MVC?

Comment: Not really.  It is a JavaScript app with MVC on the client-side.  I wanted to get data via REST from the server though, so I am using WebAPI.  I suppose I can and probably will use models on the server as well, but some calls will have very dynamic parameters that I would rather catch in something like a JObject than a predefined model.

Comment: I should add that I am very new to the Microsoft world.  I come from a LAMP background so I could easily overlook the proper way to do things in this environment.

Comment: Are you asking how to do optional parameters in C#? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: It was really more about REST and a method for a specific resource and a method for a list of resources.  It is the additional params needed in both cases that confuses me.  I want them to be routed to the correct methods, but since it is automatically putting them in one object I am not sure how to handle it.  Sorry If I am failing at explaining what I am trying to do.

Comment: Why do you want to use multiple parameters when you can just use dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}"); Console.WriteLine(d.number); Console.WriteLine(d.str);
Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

For example -

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
```

or

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}")]
public Order GetOrderByCustomer(int customerId, int orderId) { ... }
```

if you need to return a list, create a method that returns a list, otherwise return the specific item requested

Answer (score 1):

Look into using JToken or the even more dynamic 'dynamic' ([Taken from here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures2ASPNETWebAPIInVisualStudio2012.aspx))

"
JSON and JavaScript is really dynamic, though, and often it's a hassle to try to "deserialize" really dynamic JSON objects into strongly-typed .NET structures. JSON.NET and ASP.NET Web API's model binding offer a happy medium - a middle ground - called JToken.

```
public class ContactController : ApiController
{
    public JToken Post(JToken contact)
    {
        return contact;
    }
}
```

Using JToken gives a dynamic container but also a DOM-like navigation model. But if that's not dynamic enough for me, why can't my method's parameter just take a "dynamic."

C# is statically typed, sure, but that doesn't mean I can't statically type something dynamic. ;)

Again, note the watch window.

Using dynamic to catch JSON post payloads

```
public class ContactController : ApiController
{
    public dynamic Post(dynamic contact)
    {
        return contact;
    }
}
```

"

Comment: I do find this helpful, but it is really just a part of what I was trying to ask.  I updated my question to help clarify what I was meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a new object for each WebAPI function that will handle the request. You can make the parameters optional with nullable properties.

```
[HttpPost]
public void SampleFunction(SampleFunctionModel model)
{

}
```

where SampleFunctionModel is:

```
public class SampleFunctionModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```