# Web API: Need to understand a web api attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

got the code from this url [How do I use WebAPI/Rest correctly when other params are needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704505/how-do-i-use-webapi-rest-correctly-when-other-params-are-needed?rq=1)

i am new in web api attribute routing

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]  
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }  

or  

[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}")]  
public Order GetOrderByCustomer(int customerId, int orderId) { ... }
```

what is the meaning of 1st and 2nd route ?

how the first and second url will look like  please add the same url for both above action ?

thanks

Comment: .../customers/AB0123/orders/17254
where AB0123 is customerId and 17254 is orderId

Comment: The full documentation (which appears to be where that code came from) can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2. Essentially those routes define the URLs that should map to those controller actions, and the parameters in curly braces map those path segments to the controller method parameters of the same name.

Comment: @Nsevens your answer is wrong, the route is expecting an integer as customerId and you are not passing one.

Comment: @JordiRuiz indeed, my bad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The route is the offset from the application base URL. The route can contain parameter which are translated by the binder, to your method parameters.

So the first route, `customers/{customerId}/orders` would be called as `https://someserver/customers/123/orders` (route = `customers/123/orders`), which will result in a call similar to `GetOrdersByCustomer(123)`.

The second route, `customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}` would be called as `https://someserver/customers/123/orders/456` (route = `customers/123/orders/456`), which will result in a call similar to `GetOrderByCustomer(123, 456)`.

Comment: my question why i should add order keyword in first route like `https://someserver/customers/123/orders` instead we could compose the url like `https://someserver/customers/123` that would be also meaningful........so tell me why orders need be there in url?

Comment: It doesn't have to, but it is easier to understand if you add that. What if you have this route next? `https://someserver/customers/123/bills/456`

Comment: @Mou if you don't add /orders I could interpret that you want to retrieve the customer entity, however adding /orders I interpret that you want to retrieve the orders from a customer.

Comment: second url actually retrieve customer and order but fist one is only related to customer then why orders keyword need to be there. please make me understand with a easy example. thanks

Comment: The first route gets the orders from one specific customer, the second one gets one specific order from one specific customer.